# How can I change the style of a ProgressBar to small?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

I have some difficulties finding the correct way to specify that a progress bar should have the small indefinite style.

I would be glad if somebody could provide an example for me and others that do a quick search for this information.

Comment: What do you call the small indefinite style? is that when the progress bar is displayed in the title bar? Can't you just use a scaling of the image?

Comment: There is a small version of the spinning graphic. I want to use it to display it inside a button to show that the button will be activated once a call to the server is finished

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The solution is to change the style to

```
<ProgressBar
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall" />
```

Comment: I searched a lot for a dark progress bar because on white the standard progress bar can nearly not be seen. I painted one myself because I couldn't find one.

Comment: I only found the drawable "spinner_black_76" at http://www.fixedd.com/projects/android_drawables_display -> other

Comment: It works but makes it way too small! Actually you may just change `layout_width` and `layout_height` to whatever value you want and it will resize accordingly (I set 30dp x 30dp and it now fits where it should)

Answer (score 16):

One more way to do it is

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
```

Ex_

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
 style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="7dip"
 arandroid:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is how to do it programmatically:

```java
ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(ctx, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

Comment: android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall

Answer (score 9):

This may be of use:

```
style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the size of progress bar easily by scaleX and scaleY property, like this:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here,

**scaleX:** To change the width, so 0.5 will reduce the width to the half of the actual width

**scaleY:** To change the height, so 0.5 will reduce the height to the half of actual height

Answer (score 3):

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--changing of color,small size spinner-->
    <style name="progressColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

you can achieve color and small size spinner by using above style in spinner

```
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/progressColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of @Rupesh Yadav, you can see a structure of the style `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small`:

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_small_white</item>
    <item name="minWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="maxWidth">16dip</item>
    <item name="minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

I can confirm that setting min and max sizes solves the problem. Setting width and height explicitly doesn't change the size of the ProgressBar. So you can make your own style.